# What are 因 and 而 doing in the sentence 他因受到热烈欢迎而高兴?

Tags: grammar, usage

A dict.cn example sentence for [热烈](http://dict.cn/%E7%83%AD%E7%83%88) is:

> 他因受到热烈欢迎而高兴
>
> tā yīn shòudào rèliè huānyíng ér gāoxìng
>
> He was pleased by the warmth of his welcome.

The translation is mostly straightforward:

- [他](http://dict.cn/%E4%BB%96) (tā) = he
- [受到](http://dict.cn/%E5%8F%97%E5%88%B0) (shòudào) = received
- [热烈](http://dict.cn/%E7%83%AD%E7%83%88) (rèliè) = warm
- [欢迎](http://dict.cn/%E6%AC%A2%E8%BF%8E) (huānyíng) = welcome
- [高兴](http://dict.cn/%E9%AB%98%E5%85%B4) (gāoxìng) = happy

But I don't understand what these two are doing in the sentence:

- [因](http://dict.cn/%E5%9B%A0) (yīn) = reason (part of [因为](http://dict.cn/%E5%9B%A0%E4%B8%BA) = because)
- [而](http://dict.cn/%E8%80%8C) (ér) = and

**Question**: What are 因 and 而 doing in the sentence 他因受到热烈欢迎而高兴?

I would probably phrase it like 他很高兴因为他受到热烈的欢迎.

Comment: It is like 因为。。。所以

Comment: I echo with Philipp. In English, it's a wrong expression "Because.... so....". But "因为...所以...." a correct in Chinese. "Because I love you, so I marry you" is a wrong expression in English, while "因为我爱你，所以我和你结婚。" is correct in Chinese.

Comment: @dan Try "because... therefore..." in English. It's a bit old-fashioned, but it works the same way

Comment: @Philipp: In fact, I prefer the word 'as' or 'for' to 'because'. 'because' seems a bit strong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[因 A 而 B] = [because of A, therefore B]

> [因 A (受到热烈欢迎) 而 B (高兴)]
>
> [Because of A (受到热烈欢迎), Therefore B (高兴)]

or

> [B because of A] ; [B for A]
>
> [B (高兴) because of A (受到热烈欢迎)]
>
> [B (高兴) for A (受到热烈欢迎)]

When A is a reason; B is an action

When A is a cause; B is a result

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation "他很高兴因为他受到热烈的欢迎. " is correct.

As I posted in the comment above, the "because...so..." structure is wrong in English, so we have to use one word ("because", "as", "for" and etc.) to interpret here.

"因 A 而 B" could be translated to "B as(or for) the reason A".

Compare with "because" and "as", I opt for "as" because "as" usually expresses the more casual reasoning than "because".

The translation for the whole sentence might be:

> He is happy as he is warmly welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

"因 ... 而 ..." is just another way to say "because". They come together.

Answer (score 0):

他很高兴因为他受到热烈的欢迎.this stress his is happy.

他因受到热烈欢迎而高兴 this stress the reason maked he happy.